# Disable WebBrowser gray feedback rectangle when tapping links

Tags: cordova, hyperlink, windows-phone, touch, webbrowser-control

When tapping on a link in the Windows Phone `WebBrowser` control, there's a semi-transparent gray rectangle that shows up to give feedback to the user. In my application (which is based on `Cordova`) I need to remove this feedback rectangle to give a more native experience for users.

Is this possible to do? If yes, then how can I do it?

I already searched the `WebBrowser` api but didn't find anything related to removing this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding to your page:

```
<meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
```

For a [css](/questions/tagged/css) solution try one of these:

```
a:active{
   background-color:transparent;
}
```

or

```
a:active{
   background: none;
}
```

If you problem still remains the same, read [this article](http://www.tricedesigns.com/2012/06/04/getting-rid-of-the-gray-box-in-phonegap-for-windows-phone/).